# Apps for Office - how to manipulate slide in Powerpoint

Tags: javascript, powerpoint, apps-for-office

I want to be able to insert some text(or anything else) into a current (or any) slide in PowerPoint using the JavaScript API. I can't find any examples.

I've also browsed through the [API Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp142185.aspx) and haven't found any clues. (I'm not even sure if this is only the common API or all of it)

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: yeah, there's not much available. On http://blogs.msdn.com/b/officeapps/archive/2012/11/27/building-apps-for-powerpoint.aspx it states that you can only use `document.setSelectedDataAsync` in an active selection to insert text. Can't do anything else it appears.